# How to access the function which is defined in derived class and not in base class in polymorphism

Tags: c++

How to access the function which is defined in derived class and not in base class in polymorphism?

```
class base {
    public:
        virtual void display ()
        {
            cout << "base" << endl;
        }
};

class derived : public base {
    public:
        void display (){
            cout << "Derived" << endl;
        }

        void goo (){
            cout << " new function in derived" << endl;
        }
};

base * global_function ( base *ptr)
{
    /**** how to invoke the derived class goo function  ---Here *****/


}

int main ()
{

    derived obj;
    global_function ( &obj );

}
```

Can anyone help me how to invoke the derived class function, which is not specified in the base class?

Comment: Why have you got in this mess?

Comment: @ user: You *can*, but you *shouldn't*. If `global_function` needs what you pass it to be a `derived`, declare it as accepting a `derived *`, not a `base *`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeap you are right, sorry didn't see that

Comment: You cannot do it *in polymorphism*. Polymorphism is when you call a function on the base class, and it does the right thing for the derived class. It must work for *any* derived class. Your function will only work for one specific derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
Derived *d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(ptr);
if (d) d->goo();
```

`dynamic_cast<Derived*>` will produce a valid `Derived*` pointer if `ptr` indeed points to `Derived`; otherwise, `NULL` pointer would be produced (note the `if` that "guards" the invocation of `goo()`).

In general, it is not a good idea to put `dynamic_cast` to excessive use: if you need to do it a lot, it points to a potential shortcoming in the design of your class hierarchy.

Comment: +1 / A little nicer still to use `if (Derived* p_d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(ptr)) ...`, such that `p_d` can't be accidentally used outside the `if`'s scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can **downcast** the base pointer

Look at [Here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php), this contain a very good explanation of what to do

*Taked from the link:*

```
Child *p = dynamic_cast<Child *>(pParent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the method but you have to *hope* that `base *ptr` is actually a `derived*` type (which, in your case, it is).

Then you can use a `dynamic_cast` to convert the pointer to the correct type:

`derived* my_ptr = dynamic_cast<derived*>(ptr)`

and call the method using `my_ptr->goo()`. If `my_ptr` evaluates to `nullptr` then `ptr` was not of the correct type. You'll need to test this else before calling `goo` else you could invoke *undefined behaviour*.

**But**, this is an anti-pattern that circumvents polymorphism. It's far better to set up your class structure so you can avoid this cast.

Comment: How to set up class structure to avoid casting ...pls can you let me know

Answer (score 0):

The solution ( dirty and not recommended ) was the following

```
base* global_function ( base *ptr ) {
    std::dynamic_cast<Derived>(*ptr).goo();
}
```

Although this might work in this specific case, just don't assume a base type pointer to contain information about foo, rather do template specialization and maintain typesafety!

```
template <typename T>
T* global_function(const T* ptr) {
    // do nothing in this case. 
}
// Specialization
template<>
base* global_function<base>(const base* ptr) {
    // invoke base methods
}

template<>
Derived* global_function<Derived>(const Derived* ptr) {
    ptr->goo();
}
```